# Remote debugging with eclipse and tomcat service

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications

I have tomcat installed as an installer on the windows7.

I am trying to remotely debug an application using eclipse.
I want to know where can I put the following code:

```
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
catalina.bat jpda start
```

There is no catalina.bat file in tomcatHome\bin\ ,in fact there is no batch file there.
The way I start tomcat is via service.

Please advice, how can I achieve remote debugging in my case.

Comment: i have the same prob, and the answer below does not help... did u solve this thing?

Comment: Hi, the answer below does help. It appears that the instillation script(in-house script used to install the portal) that installs the Tomcat does not create tomcatxw.exe. In general case, where no in-house scripts are used the following answer is very applicable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `<tomcat-dir>/bin` and double-click on `tomcatxw.exe` where x is your tomcat version number. On the Java tab specify the following JVM parameters:

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=<port>,server=y,suspend=n
```

Put them before any `-D` parameter, use separate lines for each, and make sure that there is no whitespace at the end of the lines.

More information [Apache Tomcat 7, Windows service HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) and [Tomcat Wiki, FAQ/Developing](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing).

Comment: It's key that you put the two arguments on their own lines - I wasted time until I saw this answer.